# Secure configuration file in clients

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, security, configuration-files

In a project we will create configuration file for each clients(Also can be sqlite in each clients instead of a configuration file). That files will include critical information like policies. Therefore end-user musn't add, delete, change that configuration file or something in the file.

I am considering to use active directory to prevent users to open folder that include my configuration file.

Is there a standart way to use secure configuration files?

EDIT:
Of course speed of reading the file is important as security

EDIT2:
I can't do that with a DB server because my policies must be accesible whithout internet connection too. A server will update that file or sqlite tables in some periods. And I am using c++.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to crush your hopes and dreams, but if your security is based on that configuration file on the client, you're screwed.

The configuration file is loaded and decrypted by your application and this means that values can be changed using special tools when the application runs.

If security is important, do those checks on the server,  not the client.

Comment: .NET? I am using c++. I couldn't understand.

Comment: @Yavuz: I'm sorry, I didn't pay attention, but in fact it doesn't really matter which technology you use, they can all be compromised if your security is baked into the client software and not the server (although managed platforms such as .NET and Java make it even more easier to compromise).

Answer (score 0):

Security is a fairly broad matter. What happens if your system is compromised? Does someone lose money? Does someone get extra points in a game? Does someone gain access to nuclear missile-launching codes? Does someones medical data get exposed to the public?

All of these are more or less important security concerns, but as you can imagine, nuclear missile-launching has higher requirements to be completely secure than some game where someone may boost their score, and money and health obviously end up somewhere in the middle of that range, with lots of other things that we could add to the list.

It also matters what type of "users" you are trying to protect against. Is it national level security experts (e.g. FBI, CIA, KGB, etc), hobby hackers, or just normal computer users? Encrypting the file will stop a regular user, and perhaps a hobby hacker, but national security experts certainly won't be foiled by that.

Ultimately, tho', if the machine holding the data also knows how to read the data, then you can not have a completely secure system. The system can be bypassed by reading the key in the code, and re-implementing any de-/encryption etc that is part of your "security". And once the data is in plain text, it can be modified and then re-encrypted and stored back.

You can of course make it more convoluted, which will mean that someone will have to have a stronger motive to work their way through your convoluted methods, but in the end, it comes down to "If the machine knows how to decrypt something, someone with access to the machine can decrypt the content".

It is up to you (and obviously your "customers" and/or "partners" whose data you are looking after), whether you think that is something you can risk or not.

Comment: actually I am not mentioning about security experts. For example I think "deep freeze" keeping some configuration infos somewhere in it where end-users musn't reach. Because if end-users can do that, change configurations set by admin and deep freeze can't be succesful. I want to know is there a standard or best way for keep that informations. Of course I know, someone can hack my program in the world.

Comment: Sure, you can use some place that needs admin rights to write to, and then only use read-only to read the configuration. But that's far from secure, unless you also have control over who has admin access to the machines. Of course, if this is the IT department of a large company, most users probably don't have admin access, and that would be it. On the other hand, if you are distributing to a large number of different sites, you never really know what access-rights a user has. I've worked for companies where admin rights are given to everyone, as well as "only IT staff has admin rights".